# Getting unresolved reference on Android S - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications, foreground-service

I'm trying to use new Notification API setForegroundServiceBehavior.
However, when trying to create a build I'm getting an unresolved reference I believe in Android S in general.
*(I'm working on a different project using Java and there seems to be no problem.)*

```
    val builder = Notification.Builder(this, CH_ID)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        builder.setForegroundServiceBehavior(Notification.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE);
    }
```

Errors:

```
Unresolved reference: S
Unresolved reference: setForegroundServiceBehavior
Unresolved reference: FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE
```

Gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 31
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 28
    targetSdkVersion 31
```

Comment: Don't know if it has anything to do with it, but I think it's recommended to use buildToolsVersion that is the same as compileSdkVersion . Maybe try "31.0.0" there

Comment: Tried changing buildToolsVersion  to "31.0.0" but issue is still occurring.

Comment: Try 1. syncing project with grade files  2. Invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: no error am facing above code. may be check with invalidate cache and restart android studio will helps

Comment: @sticky did you try?

Comment: As it turned out this was a problem caused by an outdated framework.jar being used in the project. Since it has higher priority during build time, the change in sdk is being overwritten/ignored.

Comment: how did you resolved this? I'm getting same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Update you **buildToolsVersion** to “32.0.0” and **compileSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** to 32. Or newer versions.